# Cannot set default locale for JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using this code but I can't set default locale other than english. I tried this with latest Mojarra version:

**faces-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>bg</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>bg</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>com.web.common.ints.Text</base-name>
            <var>text</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

Java class to load properties files:

```
public class Text extends ResourceBundle
{
    protected static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "com.web.common.ints.text";
    protected static final String BUNDLE_EXTENSION = "properties";
    protected static final Control UTF8_CONTROL = new UTF8Control();

    public Text()
    {
        setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME,
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(), UTF8_CONTROL));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key)
    {
        return parent.getObject(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getKeys()
    {
        return parent.getKeys();
    }

    protected static class UTF8Control extends Control
    {
        public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
        {
            // The below code is copied from default Control#newBundle() implementation.
            // Only the PropertyResourceBundle line is changed to read the file as UTF-8.
            String bundleName = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
            String resourceName = toResourceName(bundleName, BUNDLE_EXTENSION);
            ResourceBundle bundle = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (reload)
            {
                URL url = loader.getResource(resourceName);
                if (url != null)
                {
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        connection.setUseCaches(false);
                        stream = connection.getInputStream();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
            }
            if (stream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
                }
                finally
                {
                    stream.close();
                }
            }
            return bundle;
        }
    }
}
```

When I open the web page he locale is always in english?
How I can set custom locale locale?

Do you have some idea how I can fix this issue?

I used this tutorial: http://jdevelopment.nl/internationalization-jsf-utf8-encoded-properties-files/

So I changed this line:

```
 private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

To:

```
locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
```

If I use the original code I get NPE. But with the second code I get always en as default locale.

Comment: Post is updated.

Comment: I didn't need to have both default-locale and supported-locale with the same value. Perhaps take the `<supported-locale>bg</supported-locale>` out.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the locale come from the browser? The locale is english b/c your browser is running on a system that says its locale is english. Under windows, I installed the spanish language pack and then I can control the default locale, or at least the locale the browser is asking for by switching the computer and opening a new browser, if I remember correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale>
            <supported-locale>zh</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>i18n.Text</base-name>
            <var>text</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2786895465419133453L;

    private Locale locale;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        locale = new Locale(language);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }

}
```

and

```
<p:submenu label="#{text['menu.language']}" style="float:right">
<p:menuitem value="#{text['menu.language.english']}" action="#{localeBean.setLanguage('en')}" oncomplete="location.reload(true)" />
<p:menuitem value="#{text['menu.language.spanish']}" action="#{localeBean.setLanguage('es')}" oncomplete="location.reload(true)"/>
<p:menuitem value="#{text['menu.language.chinese']}" action="#{localeBean.setLanguage('zh')}" oncomplete="location.reload(true)"/>
```

and then various `i18n/Text_en.properties`, `i18n/Text_es.properties`, `i18n/Text_zh.properties`.

Comment: In the Q (the edited version) `locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();` throws an NPE. And he nowhere shows how he even tries to set a (different/default) locale (like you do). And he does not know the difference between supported and 'default' locale. Instead posts unrelated code. OP is not that investigative... unfortunately. I removed my comments since 99% of the time, comments do not help here and OP in 95% of the cases ask about a **complete** example. But thanks for trying to help out. Good luck. OP has dozens of other unanswered JSF questions, so good luck

Comment: IF OP would have posted the method call in combination with the error in google, "https://www.google.nl/search?q=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()+throws+an+NullPointerException" he would have gotten a lot of info. Referring to those posts, telling us which one does help or not, what does happen etc... would have been way better (but OP does not want to do that)